# Gulp-sass will not compile to CSS

Tags: sass, npm, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm not able to get grunt-sass to compile to .css. Have seen a load of other similar posts and utilized suggestions but nothing seems to work.

I can get other plugins working fine (for example 'del' to delete stuff, shown here) so it seems my environment is ok, and i can get ordinary vanilla sass compile/watch to work fine.

Here's my setup just in case:

OSX Maverics 10.9.5

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

$ sass -v
Sass 3.4.9 (Selective Steve)

$ npm -v
2.1.12

$ brew -v
Homebrew 0.9.5
```

Here's the project directory structure:

```
    ├── index.html
    │   
    ├── scss
    │    └── base.scss
    │          ├── _partial1.scss
    │          └── _partial2.scss
    │
    ├── assets
    │      └── css
    │           └── Nothing yet!
    │
    ├── deltest
    │    └── save.txt
    │
    ├── gulpfile.js
    │
    └── node_modules
         └── etc ...
```

Here's my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('gsas', function() {
    gulp.src('./scss/base.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ includePaths : ['./scss/'] }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css'))
});

del(['!deltest/save.txt', 'deltest/delete.txt'], function (err, deletedFiles) {
    console.log('Files deleted:', deletedFiles.join(', '));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    console.log('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARGH!');
});
```

Can anyone see what is wrong here?

---

**UPDATED - with same task silently failing on a windows box:**

Here's the gulpfile.js from the windows box test and I'm not even @importing any partials (the dir structure is *exactly* as shown in the task setup, which i pulled straight from the actual plugin example):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

del(['delete/delete.txt', '!delete/save.txt'], function (err, deletedFiles) {
    console.log('Files deleted:', deletedFiles.join(', '));
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    console.log("Made it!");
});
```

In this example again I'm getting the 'del' task to run fine but gulp-sass fails silently and it's really baffling.

Comment: May be you should import ````_partial1.scss```` and other into base.scss (@import "partial1") and remove includePath from sass compiler. I think, it will help you.

Comment: The partials are imported already via @import. Tried the other option of removing includePath, stripped down to the bear essentials but no joy am afraid. The whole shebang gets through the default task so it's driving me a bit nuts tbh!
Thanks though

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Hey @Ben no it's failing silently.
I edited my original post to reflect a test i did on a windows box which is _also_ failing silently, could you pls have a look at the edit?

Comment: If it helps, on the windows box the setup is as follows:
npm -v: 1.4.28, sass -v: 3.4.9 (Selective Steve), gulp -v: CLI version 3.8.10

Comment: Exactly what command are you using to run gulp?

Comment: `gulp`
It compiles etc, shows the default task console.log, executes various tasks but just not gulp-sass

Comment: In the code you have posted in this question, running `gulp` will not execute the `sass` task since the `default` task does not depend on any other tasks.

Comment: Try running `gulp sass` and see if you get the compiled css.

Comment: So do i need to add it into the default task? I haven't see that in any documentation or other examples. I have used 'watch' in default but made no diff with this.

Comment: Sorry missed your last before i added my last - so i ran `gulp sass` on the pc and it worked :)
Just gonna hit it on the mac, back shortly ... ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the `sass` task to execute when you run `gulp` from the command-line, add it as a dependency of the `default` task:

```
gulp.task('default', ['sass'], function() {
  //other stuff
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben just ran it on the mac and all's fine. Also duly noted the dependency in default.
Cheers for your help!