# Gulp-sass won't compile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp

Hoping for someone to help me get my SCSS files to compile using gulp.

I've been doing lots of reading on this (http://www.devworkflows.com/posts/getting-scss-auto-prefixer-and-source-map-to-play-nice/) and followed this stack overflow conversation ([Gulp-sass will not compile to CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412516/gulp-sass-will-not-compile-to-css)) among others. I still can't get my `.scss` to compile using my gulp script.

When I run `gulp sass` the process outputs:

```
[16:25:32] Working directory changed to ~/projects/theBeta
[16:25:32] Using gulpfile ~/projects/theBeta/gulpfile.js
[16:25:32] Starting 'sass'...
[16:25:32] Finished 'sass' after 6.37 ms
```

However there is no output file. I have been able to get this to work via the command line using this command - `sass scss/_bootstrap.scss:css/compiled/bootstrap.css`

Here's the script in question:

```
// Compile sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('./app/styles/scss/_bootstrap.scss')
    .pipe(sass({sourcemap: true}))
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/styles/css/compiled'));
})
```

Is there something subtle I am missing, or a behavior I am not understanding/aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `return` front of `gulp.src` and rename `_bootstrap.scss` to `bootstrap.scss` as it's not an include:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/styles/scss/bootstrap.scss')
    .pipe(sass({sourcemap: true}))
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/styles/css/compiled'));
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did try some variation of this (not this exact solution). I will try it when I get home today and keep you posted on the result. To clarify though, my `_bootstrap.scss` should be renamed to `bootstrap.scss`? Or I should simply refer to it as that in the url and sass knows the difference?

Comment: Yes, the `_bootstrap.scss` file should be renamed to `bootstrap.scss`. Alternatively, create a new `app.scss` and `@import "bootstrap";` in it. Sass says: "The underscore lets Sass know that the file is only a partial file and that it should not be generated into a CSS file. Sass partials are used with the @import directive."

Comment: Man, thank you! This was incredibly helpful. All is working.

Comment: @camerow The pleasure's mine :)